# Integrate Coverity Report into Jenkins Output

Tags: jenkins, command-line, coverity

I have `Coverity` building with `Jenkins` and the report can be viewed in `Synopsys Coverity's` web interface. How can I get a report to be in my `Jenkins` output?

I have looked at other posts and found plugin documentation saying it was deprecated back in 2018.

**EDIT:**
There is an updated version of the plug-in, found documentation at https://synopsys.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/INTDOCS/overview?homepageId=622607
I am using `Version 2.3.1`